# Importing JSON to Firebase getting Invalid or Unexpected Token error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to import a json file to firebase using this code

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./service_key.json");


admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "MY DB URL"
});


const firestore = admin.firestore();
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "files");


fs.readdir(directoryPath, function(err, files) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log("Unable to scan directory: " + err);
  }



  files.forEach(function(file) {
    var lastDotIndex = file.lastIndexOf(".");

    var menu = require("./files/" + file); #<---------


    menu.forEach(function(obj) {
      firestore
        .collection(file.substring(0, lastDotIndex))
        .doc(obj.itemID)
        .set(obj)
        .then(function(docRef) {
          console.log("Document written");
        })

        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

I think I've narrowed down the issue to this line:
var menu = require("./files/" + file)

I just cant figure out what the problem is. Ive successfully ran it on one file and tried on another and now neither files work anymore. I've cleared my Firestore so there's nothing in it and I think I've eliminated the json file as the problem.

I'm on Mac so maybe the pathing is incorrect? I'm not sure

the Node.js script is running in a folder that contains the sub folder 'files' where the json files are contained.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the contents of the file that you're requiring.  If the error message is dealing with that line, it might be complaining about `file`.  Also please edit the question to show the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly known issue, that `require` is not working with variables.

You are right that this line is causing this problem. Unfortunately there is no easy magic solution (at least I haven't found any yet).

I have done some research there, and haven't found any doc saying clearly "this is not working". This is related with order of executions, and I believe require statements are executed before the rest of the code, or something like that.

I strongly suggest to study this subject. If you google like: "js require with variable", "require dynamically in js" or something like this. You will find tones of questions, articles about in and I am sure you will find, as well, many tries to solve it...